# Spring AOP - method invoke() doesn't occurs

Tags: java, spring, aop

I have a default-context.xml

```
<beans
xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-2.0.4.xsd">
<!-- some other beans -->
<bean id="licenseTestingAdvice" class="mypackage.LicenseTestingAdvice" />
<bean id="jdbcTemplate" class="mypackage.ProxyFactoryBean">
    <property name="interceptorNames">
        <list>
            <idref bean="licenseTestingAdvice" />
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="target">
        <value>mypackage.JDBCTemplate</value>
    </property>
    <property name="proxyTargetClass" value="true" />
</bean>
```

And a LicenseTestingAdvice.java:

```
import org.aopalliance.intercept.MethodInterceptor;
import org.aopalliance.intercept.MethodInvocation;

import java.lang.reflect.Method;

public class LicenseTestingAdvice implements MethodInterceptor {
    @Override
    public Object invoke(MethodInvocation inv) throws Throwable {
        Method method = inv.getMethod();

        System.out.println(String.format(">> Method %s was called before", method.getName()));
        inv.proceed();
        System.out.println(String.format(">> Method %s was called after", method.getName()));

        return null;  //To change body of implemented methods use File | Settings | File Templates.
    }
}
```

When I call execute() method of JDBCTemplate class - invoke() method doesn't called. How to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

This `<value>mypackage.JDBCTemplate</value>` should be a reference to a bean or an inner bean.    Also, interceptor name should be the name of the bean, not the reference to it. Something like:

```
<bean id="myJdbcTemplate" class="mypackage.JDBCTemplate"/>
<bean id="jdbcTemplate" class="mypackage.ProxyFactoryBean">
    <property name="interceptorNames">
        <list>
            <value>licenseTestingAdvice</value>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="target" ref="myJdbcTemplate"/>
    <property name="proxyTargetClass" value="true" />
</bean>
```

Comment: Ok. But **mypackage.JDBCTemplate** has a constructor with one parameter. I must also include it to xml. This parameter is an instance of one more class and so on and so on. Why do I need this? An instance of *JDBCTemplate* class has been created from code without using beans. Or to make it work I need to create an instance of **JDBCTemaple** using beans only? :-(